# Image won't load in UIImageView iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to display an image in a UIImageView only in the first launch of the app. So after using NSUserDefaults to detect that successfully I try to load an image called firstLaunch.png in the MainViewController.

I created the UIImageView IBOutlet and connected and everything works fine but the image DOESN'T load. Though later somewhere else in my code I can update the UIImageView successfully. Here is my line where I try to load the image to the UIImageView:

```
[countDownImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"firstLaunch.png"]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try getting the path to the file.
So assuming the image is in the app bundle, get the path before with :

```
NSString *imgPath = [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForRessource:@"firstLaunch"
                                                    ofType:@"png"];
[countDownImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgPath]];
```

Another way is :

```
[countDownImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"firstLaunch.png"]];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually tried the 1st method you suggested already but it didn't work. Maybe because I read the image to an NSData. Anyways the 2nd method worked great.`[countDownImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"firstLaunch.png"]];`